# Proof by induction $1\cdot 3 \cdot 5\cdots (2n-1) / (2 \cdot 4\cdot 6\cdots 2n) \leq 1/ \sqrt{n+1}, \forall n \geq 1, n\in \mathbb N$

Tags: inequality, induction, products

Prove by induction for

$$ \frac{\left(1\right)\left(3\right)\left(5\right)...\left(2n-1\right)}{\left(2\right)\left(4\right)\left(6\right)...\left(2n\right)}\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}\quad \text{for all integers}\quad n \ge 1$$

My current inductive step:
$$ \frac{(2(k+1))!}{2^{2\left(k+1\right)}((k+1)!)^2} = \frac{2k+1}{2(k+1)} \cdot\frac{(2k)!}{2^{2k}\left(k!\right)^2}$$

I'm not sure how to proceed to show 
$$ \frac{2k+1}{2(k+1)} \cdot \frac{(2k)!}{2^{2k}\left(k!\right)^2} \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+2}}$$

Comment: Have a look at my answer here for some ideas: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260778/prove-frac12-cdot-frac34-cdot-frac56-cdot-cdot-frac2n-12n-le-fra/2260842#2260842

Comment: Use the Gamma function.

Comment: Thx for the answer! Didn't realise it was answered before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to use factorials here, you can do it with basic arithmetic. The base case is

$$\frac{1}{2} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},$$

which you can square both sides to find that it's true.

Then we note that if $f(n)$ is the fraction on the left of the inequality, then $f(n+1) = f(n)\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}$.

So we assume for induction that $f(n) \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}$, then:

$$f(n) \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}$$
$$f(n)\frac{2n+1}{2n+2} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}$$
$$f(n+1) \leq \frac{2n+1}{\sqrt{n+1}(2n+2)}$$

Now we want to know if

$$\frac{2n+1}{\sqrt{n+1}(2n+2)} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+2}}$$
$$(2n+1)\sqrt{n+2} \leq \sqrt{n+1}(2n+2)$$
$$(2n+1)^2(n+2) \leq (n+1)(2n+2)^2$$
$$4 n^3 + 12 n^2 + 9 n + 2 \leq 4 n^3 + 12 n^2 + 12 n + 4$$
$$9 n \leq 12 n + 2$$

Which is easy to see to be true for any positive $n$.

Comment: Thx for the solution!